# HTML/PHP mail() : Content Not Showing in Email with Attachment sent Through PHP

Tags: php, html, email, email-attachments, mime

The issue: Emails sent with HTML and attachment do not show content. There is no issue with the attachment. Before I attempted to send it as an HTML email, the message and attachment were fine.

The code: I am using the following code to send emails with attachments:

```
    //Email to Customer or Tech
    $file = "../PDF/phptopdf/".$_GET['pdf'];
    $lgth = strlen($_GET['pdf']);
    $intsta = strpos($_GET['pdf'],'/')+1;
    $intend = $lgth - strpos($_GET['pdf'],'.');
    $intendname = $lgth - strpos($_GET['pdf'],'_');
    $filename = substr($_GET['pdf'],$intsta,-$intend);

    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

    // a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
    $separator = md5(time());

    // carriage return type (RFC)
    $eol = "\r\n";

    // main header (multipart mandatory)
    $headers = "From: ".$_SESSION['userFName']." ".$_SESSION['userLName']." <".$_SESSION['email'].">" . $eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;

    // message
    $body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . $eol;

    if ($_POST['sendToTech'] == '1') {
        $mailto = $_POST['techEmail'];
        $subject = 'New Work Order for '.$compName;
        $pos = strpos($_POST['techName'],' ');
        $techFName = substr($_POST['techName'],0,$pos);
        $message = "<html><body>";
        $message .= "<table style='border:1px solid #000;font-size:18px;line-height:20px;'><tr><td style='text-align:center;padding:10px;'><img src='MY LOGO URL' /></tr></td>";
        $message .= "<tr><td style='padding:10px;'>";
        $message .= "Hello ".$techFName.", <br/><br/>";
        $message .= "I have assigned work order #00-".$_GET['idQ']." for ".$compName." to you. <br/>";
        $message .= "The work is scheduled for ".date('F jS, Y \a\t g:i A',strtotime($serviceDate))." at ".$address.". <br/>";
        $message .= "Click on the attachment to view the work order or <a href='MYURL".$_GET['pdf']."'>Click Here</a>. <br/><br/>";
        $message .= "Thank you, <br/>";
        $message .= $_SESSION['userFName']."<br/><br/></tr></td></table></body></html>";
        $body .= $message . $eol;

        // attachment
        $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
        $body .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol;
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
        $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol;
        $body .= $content . $eol;
        $body .= "--" . $separator . "--";
        //SEND Mail
        if (mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
            echo "<span class='message mg'>Work Order #00-".$idQ." has been emailed to ".$_POST['techName']." at ".$_POST['techEmail']."</span><br/>";
        } else {
            $msg[] = "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
            echo "<span class='message alert'>An error occured while attempting to send Work Order #00-".$idQ." to ".$_POST['techEmail']."</span>";
        }
    }
```

When the email arrives it looks like this:
[Email in Gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLQll.png)

But, when I look into the original message I see the content that is not displayed: 
[Original Message View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GD3m.png)

Solutions that I have attempted:

1. Removing "This is a multi-part message in MIME format" ([PHP mail function html content not visible in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907773/php-mail-function-html-content-not-visible-in-email))
2. Changing  `$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . $eol;`  -- to `text/plain` (just to see if that would do anything...)
3. Changing  `$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;` -- from `7bit` and `quoted-printable`
4. Removing `<html><body>` and closing tags

Comment: i suggest not rolling you own and using phpmailer or swiftmailer

Comment: I have seen this suggestion all over and I agree that it would be the best solution and probably will be the solution that I use. That being said, in the spirit of education, I would like to know what the problem is.

Comment: maybe some one will see something obvious, but personally the only way i could debug this is testing it locally, and that would take to much time. Making mail send, look good, and arrive safely is a large part of my job, its a rather complex and moving target

Comment: @nogad I have come to realize that. I see why everyone says to use phpmailer and avoid the headache.